# How to access variables in ScriptComponent in a DataFlow task

Tags: ssis, bids

I am trying to access the package level variable "FirstRecord".  However, I can't do :

```
dts.variables("FirstRecord").value = Truth
```

How do I access variables in a DataFlow Script Component?

Comment: I guess more than anything, what i need to do is (if its possible to do this outside a data flow task) write to an xml file from a table in a db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is different in a Script Component in a Data Flow Task than it is in a Script Task.  You are using the syntax for the Script Task.

You can try this to assign a value to the package variable from a Script Component

```
Variables.FirstRecord = Truth
```

You can only assign values to a package variable in the PreExecute or PostExecute procedures.